# How to bind to a ComboBox in WPF with Data and Value pointing to 2 properties

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-4.0

I have a class with similar structure as given below:-

```
public class Sample
{
    public List<string> Names { get; private set; }
    public List<int> IDs { get; private set; }

    // Some logic to populate these collections.
}
```

Now in another XAML file, I need to bind Names property to a ComboBox and based on the selection I need to get the corresponding ID as selected value. Is there way I can solve this problem using binding?

I have an object of Sample class in my model like below:-

```
public class Model
{
    public Sample Object
    {
       get { return _sample; }
       set { _sample = value; }
    }
}
```

I'm not allowed to change the Sample entity class. Please guide me on how to solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean `corresponding id`? Those are two separate lists.

Comment: @gleng The first item should use the item at the index 0 from each list to create it's text/value, the second combo box item is based on the values at index 1 of each list, and so on.

Comment: @gleng: Each Id is related to a name in my case. I know actually it should be something like a Dictionary, but I cannot change it at this moment.

Comment: @Servy: This will not work in my case, I can have only one item in the Names collection with a corresponding value in IDs as 10.

Comment: @Arun Then you'll need to explain how the items are supposed to be correlated, if it's not by index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to wrap the `Name` and `ID` into a separate class, then bind the `ItemsSource` to the collection of Name/ID pairs.  Set the `DisplayMemberPath` on the `ComboBox` to `"Name"`.

On the View Model, you can have a property for the selected Name/ID pair, or just the selected ID.  If you want to do the latter, just set `SelectedValuePath` to `"ID"` and bind `SelectedValue` to the ID property on your view model (note that if you do it this way, you can use the anonymous class projection from Servy's answer).  Otherwise, just bind `SelectedItem` to your selected Name/ID pair property (this version requires a named class).

Comment: I have generated an IDictionary with ID as key and Name as value and then bound this to the ItemSource. Now it works!

Answer (score 3):

You need to merge the two different lists into a single list of an object with two values before binding, fortunately doing so is rather straightforward, just use `Zip`:

```
var data = sample.Names.Zip(sample.IDs, (name, id)=> new{name, id});
```

Then bind to `data` as you normally would.

Comment: This is ugly, how would you get the selected item id after populating the `ComboBox` ?

Comment: I explain that in my answer.  It can definitely be done with an anonymous projection like this (assuming the items are, in fact, correlated by index).

Comment: @NovitchiS You can create a new named type if you need to, or use `Tuple`, this is just a starting place.